# How to change slides using setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my JS code so far. Right now I can click on each button on the slider and it will change to the corresponding slide.

```
$('.slide-nav').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// get current slide
var current = $('.flex--active').data('slide'),
  // get button data-slide
  next = $(this).data('slide');
console.log(current);
$('.slide-nav').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

if (current === next) {
  return false;
} else {
  $('.slider__wrapper').find('.flex__container[data-slide=' + next + ']').addClass('flex--preStart');
  $('.flex--active').addClass('animate--end');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.flex--preStart').removeClass('animate--start flex--preStart').addClass('flex--active');
    $('.animate--end').addClass('animate--start').removeClass('animate--end flex--active');
   }, 900);
  }
 });
```

the slider I am working with looks like this one to see the html/css 
https://codepen.io/mikun/pen/YWgqEX

So in addition to clicking to change slides I would like to scroll to change slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate the click function this way:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(".slide-nav.active").next().click();
}, 1000);
```

You need to check if this is the last and try this:

```
setInterval(function () {
  if ($(".slide-nav.active").next().length > 0)
    $(".slide-nav.active").next().click();
  else
    $(".slide-nav").first().click();
}, 1000);
```

**Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwBVzo**

Comment: thank you!!!! perfect!!! Pretty much exactly what I was looking to do but I am going to tweak it somewhat thank you sir!

Comment: how can I do this with a scroll function?

Comment: @EmilyMcMullin You can do it on `window.scroll()`